# Remove login from Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First off, the code blocks on the site were acting wonky for me, so I used pastebin instead. Sorry :X [Here you go](http://pastebin.com/QigRvXe5)

Basically, this is a Google Chrome extension which requires a login to use the rest of the features. My friend has given me the challenge of removing the login and make it possible to simply run the extension and use all the features. I have tried simply removing the bits of code involving "userEmail" and the "Registered," and the login screen was removed. However, the extension did not work correctly, as the start button refused to do anything.

So my goal as said before is to remove the login screen. By the way, this is one file within the extension. There are other files, but I believe this is the only one which deals with logging in. If you feel like you need the rest of the files of the extension, it is found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o65xsus11kuzap6/jbd3_0FrmC).

If you feel like you actually need the extension itself, just let me know.
Thanks in advance for all help given, whether it be giving ideas or modifying the code yourselves!

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at. Are you seeing an error in the console log? Have you tried general debugging strategies like console log statements and use of the chrome web inspector debugger to see what happens when you click or add the event listener for clicking?

Comment: Will try this when I get back home!

Comment: Just got home and been playing around with it while looking at the console, but I think I'm looking in the wrong place. Is Tools --> JavaScript Console the correct place?

Comment: Go to your Window -> Extensions. Find your extension. Select "inspect views" for your background.html. If you have a page or browser action popup, right click on it and select "inspect Element".

Answer (score 1):

I would change as little as possible. Instead of deleting large portions, just make tiny changes.

Set the `userIsRegistered` variable to default to true, then empty out the `checkRegistered` function, so that it does nothing, but still exists.